# Role security with active directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security

I have to ensure the security of a asp.net website at work. They asked me to do a role based security with the active directory of my work so I could do a sitemap and give the right access at the right person.

Which class of the framework should I use? make generic identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already built into AD authentication. If you are authenticating against the AD, either via NTLM logins or an AD connected forms authentication setup then the thread identity will contain the groups the user belongs to, and the role based parts of the sitemap control will work.

Specifically you use the *WindowsTokenRoleProvider*. This is a one way role manager (you can't add people to groups - you have to use the AD tools for that. The use the sitemap's [built in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx) support for trimming site maps according to role.

Comment: you mind taking a look at this? it's odd as hell and I cant get any expert answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147132/active-directory-group-membership-checking-in-net-4-5

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a RoleManager.  Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I need for every user that goes on the intranet to be looked up by the Active directory, then build the right menu depending on the roles and acces the user have.

should i use the RoleManager or a class like that?