# Active Directory Group Membership Checking in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, active-directory

I have an ASP.Net MVC application using Windows Authentication, and I am checking group membership for security on controller actions.

Simple as it sounds, I've found no other Question that can resolve the problem I am experiencing.

#### First Attempt: [Authorize]

The classic method is to simply slap an `Authorize` data annotation attribute on the controller action and go to town:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"domain\groupName1")]
```

No dice. I am prompted for credentials. Usually this means something is wrong with the Windows Authentication configuration but it's setup fine: (1) `HttpContext.User` is a `WindowsPrincipal` object, and (2) I confirmed another known group name works.

#### Second Attempt: IsInRole()

The next step taken was to go a more old fashioned route and use `IPrincipal.IsInRole()`, and again, one returns `false`, the other `true`.

```
var wp = (WindowsPrincipal)User;

// false
var inGroup1 = wp.IsInRole(@"domain\groupName1");
// true
var inGroup2 = wp.IsInRole(@"domain\groupName2");
```

Stumped... so I hit up my systems nerds and we double check everything. User is a group member? Yes. Group name is spelled correctly? Yes. The next step was to snag the SID.

#### Third Attempt: Search Identity's Group Collection

In my controller I check the `WindowsIdentity` and look through the group collection for the SID of the troublesome group:

```
var wi = (WindowsIdentity)wp.Identity;
var group = wi.Groups.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Value == "group1-sidValue");
```

The `group` variable is the `SecurityIdentifier` object. Because it is not null, we can be certain that this current user is a member of the group that both the `[Authorize()]` or `IsInRole()` attempts fail to confirm.

#### Fourth Attempt: DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

At this point, I'm going nuts and add reference to the AccountManagement APIs. I search the domain context for the `GroupPrincipal` by both name and SID:

```
   var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain");
   var gp1byName = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "groupName1")
   var gp1bySid = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Sid, "group1-sidValue");
```

Both group principal variables are ripe with the same object, and I verified through a watch variable that the principal's `Members` collection contains a `UserPrincipal` object with the same SID as the current `WindowsPrincipal` on `HttpContext`.

#### Question:

What in the hell have I missed here? Why would both role checking methodologies fail when it is plain and clear through object exploration that the user is a valid member of this given group?

The fact that one group checks fine and the other does not seems the most strange part at this point.

Comment: It's not clear if Fourth Attempt works correct.
Also there is fifth way of getting the user details: to use LDAP query.

Comment: @PuterdoBorato - Both 3rd and 4th attempt prove the user in question is part of the group in question. the group that `IsInRole()` and `[Authorize]` are failing... I'm asking, why would it fail to resolve them either way when the remaining two ways clearly validate the User's association to the Group

Comment: Could you try giving "LocalLogon" permission to user you are trying to authorize by using [Authorize] or IsInRole? Could you please tell the result of such attempt? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Answer:

Essentially it's translation issues between `WindowsIdentity` and `NTAccount` (both of these System.Security.Principal) and lastly, the actual Active Directory entry.

When validating a `WindowsIdentity` against AD, if you want to use anything other than the Sam or the Sid, you will need to use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

*Caveat: In .Net 4.5 the security principals include Claims but that's out of context.*

---

#### Long Explanation:

In a Windows Authenticated web application, `HttpContext.User` is a `WindowsPrincipal` object wrapping an underlying `WindowsIdentity`.

`WindowsIdentity` has for most intents and purposes only two properties with which the authenticated user can be identified: `Name` and `User`.

These properties translate to two properties on the identity's corresponding AD account entry:

`WindowsIdentity.Name` = `SamAccountName`

`WindowsIdentity.User` = `SID`

The `[Authorize]` filter attribute ultimately calls `IsInRole(string role)` on the underlying principal... and the `IsInRole()` string overload instantiates an `NTAccount` with the `role` (the "SamAccountName" in an AD entry).

This explains the failure in #1 and #2 above.

To authorize the `HttpContext.User` against anything but his/her Sid or SamAccountName, you'll need `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` or classic LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASP.Net MVC application using Windows Authentication, and I am checking group membership for security on controller actions. Simple as it sounds, I've found no other Question that can resolve the problem I am experiencing. 
Took me a lot of time to find something
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/test-for-user-group-membership-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

My code to check if user belongs to an AD group :

```
foreach (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference group in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
{
     if (String.Equals(group.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString(), @"your_domain_name\your_group_name", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
         // the user belongs to a group 
     }
}
```

That is all I needed beside `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in Web.config file